# How to set the map to a particular location on map load

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am using a mapkit I found on Github to plot directions, but the problem is when the mapview loads it shows US at startup and then moves to the location where route is plotted. Is there any way to show Australia instead at the startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this to initialize the Map View, and it works perfectly for me :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  XX.XXX, .longitude =  X.XXX};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  X.XX, .longitudeDelta =  X.XX};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
```

Then, use the `setRegion` method for your `MKMapView`

Is it that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D maxCoord = {-90.0f, -180.0f};
CLLocationCoordinate2D minCoord = {90.0f, 180.0f};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};

    region.center.longitude = (minCoord.longitude + maxCoord.longitude) / 2.0;
    region.center.latitude = (minCoord.latitude + maxCoord.latitude) / 2.0;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxCoord.longitude - minCoord.longitude);
    region.span.latitudeDelta = (maxCoord.latitude - minCoord.latitude);

[self.mainMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

You can adjust the maxCoord and minCoord inputs to the values you'd like for Australia.